# Nodejs/nestjs: Getting a 13s response time from my multiple crawlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, cheerio

I'm building a newspaper app similar to a Flipboard briefing mobile app! using nodejs nestjs framework.

So I'm crawling into multiple websites to get data and I ended up with an array has over 60 Item just for the first page collected together from each website and response time in a range 10s to 15s witch not acceptable for just 3 websites!!!!

I searched for this and I found that nestjs provide a cache service and it was great by caching results ending up with 20ms but!

> **I'm not using any type of DB as I'm not scraping data! just titles and URLs for iframes**

My problems are:

1. How to paginate into that 60 items per page and in the end make a new request for the next page from my crawlers.
2. The first user will face that 15s response time every 6 Hours ( my cache end ) so how to make the server automatic caching data not waiting for a request

The Crawler code: ( I have 3 functions like this almost the same just CSS selectors changing )

```
async getArticlesFromTechWD(page: number) {
    const html = await get('https://www.tech-wd.com/wd/category/news/page/' + page);

    // Cheerio
    let $ = load(html);

    function formatingDate(date) {
        let months = ["يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "إبريل", "مايو", "يونيو",
            "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"
        ];

        date = date.replace('،', '').split(' ');
        const year = date[2];
        const month = (months.indexOf(date[1]) + 1).toString().length == 1 ? '0' + (months.indexOf(date[1]) + 1) : (months.indexOf(date[1]) + 1)
        const day = date[0];

        return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    }

    const articles = $('#masonry-grid .post-element').map(function () {
        return {
            title: $('.thumb-title', this).text().trim(),
            date: formatingDate($('.date', this).text().trim()),
            url: $('.thumb-title a', this).attr('href'),
            image: $('.slide', this).css('background-image').replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/\"/gi, ""),
            src: 'www.tech-wd.com'
        }
    }).get();

    return articles;
}
```

Merging all crawlers data into one array:

```
async getAllArticles(page: number, size: number) {

    const skip = size * (page - 1);

    // First crawler ( has an optional page pram default is page 1 )
    const unlimitTech = await this.getArticlesFromUnlimitTech();

    // Second crawler ( has an optional page pram default is page 1 )
    const tectWd = await this.getArticlesFromTechWD();

    // Merge them and sorted by date ( DESC )
    const all = unlimitTech.concat(tectWd).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

    return all;

}
```

Comment: You should really show some code.

Comment: Sorry about that I was writing the question in hurry! I have updated the question with some code ...thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of one at a time:

```
const unlimitTech = await this.getArticlesFromUnlimitTech();
const tectWd = await this.getArticlesFromTechWD();
```

You can do both at the same time:

```
const [unlimitTech, tectWd] = await Promise.all([
  this.getArticlesFromUnlimitTech(),
  this.getArticlesFromTechWD()
])
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to do multiple things at once. Start your all your requests and then `await` on each of them at the end. At least your timings sound like you're waiting on each request to finish before starting the next one.

Comment: This not possible with NodeJS as it single-threaded so it has to do each task at the time

Comment: @hesham Node is asynchronous which means it can do other things when IO is blocking.

Comment: @heshamshawky workers work on separate thread in Web, child_process works on separate thread in node. And asynchronous code under the hood launches in separate threads tasks in loop.